# How to convert to a specific object before I select a new list object in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List , object "a" whose type is 1, 2, 3, I want to test object

`a.type == 1` or `a.type == 2` or `a.type == 3`

Then I will convert to my data type, for example `a.type == 1` convert to `classtype1`, or `a.type == 2` then convert to `classtype == 2` .. next I will select a new list to save All three types of this object.

Comment: I just used Stack Overflow, I do not understand why I was downvote ???

Comment: Sorry for the bad experience. But you got the downvotes because of the quality of your question. You should try to explain your problem in more detail and also provide a sample of what you allready tried.

Comment: Hi Tran Audi check my answer meet your requirement

Comment: One thing I don't understand is do you have a field of type int do indicate the type and you want to create new objects or are there already in the types you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will meet your requirement it seems

```
List<object> myObjects = new List<object>();

        myObjects.Add(1);
        myObjects.Add("Ravi");
        myObjects.Add(new DateTime());

        for (var i = 0; i < myObjects.Count; i++)
        {
            var myObject = myObjects[i];

            if (myObject is int) // or can use if(myObject.GetType() == typeof(int))
            {

            }
            else if (myObject is string)
            {

            }
            else if (myObject is DateTime)
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, I was too abusive to Linq :)

Comment: @TranAudi You can do anything using linq that you can do with loops. You question is still unclear. Try editing the question to make it more clear. From what I can see what you want is a simple group by but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the type wit the is keyword, like this

```
List<object> a = new List<object>();
List<string> aStrings = new List<string>();
List<int> aInts = new List<int>();

//insert objects in a

foreach(object o in a)
{
    if(o is string)
    {
       aStrings.Add(o as string);
    }
    else if(a is int)
    {
       aInts.Add(o as int);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to browse all the elements in the <a> list and select three styles and then include them in a <b> list

Comment: I've editied my answer. Im not sure if thats what you mean. If not, please provide further information of what you are trying to do

Comment: Thank you, I found the answer. Very sorry, the question is not clear